# Different file byte array in C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, byte

I have an issue with a byte array from a file.

I get the byte array from a file in C# and VB.Net but it´s different in both languajes. It´s a minimal different but it produces a failure.

This is my code in VB.NET:

```
Private Function GetStreamAsByteArray(ByVal stream As System.IO.Stream) As Byte()
    stream.Position = 0
    Dim streamLength As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length)
    Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength) {}
    stream.Read(fileData, 0, streamLength)
    stream.Position = 0
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("array_bytes_vb.txt", Convert.ToBase64String(fileData.ToArray()))
    Return fileData
End Function
```

This is my code in .NET

```
private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("array_bytes_net.txt",Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()));
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

If I compare both files, only there is a different at the final of the byte array:

[Different comparing string of both files char by char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg5X5.png)

What can be the error?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netcore-3.1) static method for this

Comment: @vasily.sib I know it, but I need to read the file with a filestream because it´s method let you improve the behaviour when the file is too big.

Comment: `Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength)` should be `Dim fileData As Byte() = New Byte(streamLength - 1)` because in VB you specify the last index of the array, whereas in C# you specify the number of elements of the array.

Comment: @MiguelSanchez you are reading a **whole** file to a big array in your code. There is no improvement over `File.ReadAllBytes`. More then that you are reading this file to a `MemoryStream` at first, and then convert it `ToArray()` - so, at some point of the time, you have 2 huge equal arrays in your memory. So I can say, that `File.ReadAllBytes` is more efficient, than shown code.

Comment: To Andrew's comment, it's a VBA-ism, but I prefer to use the `0 To {n}` form of specifying the dimensions of an array (harkening back to happier days when we weren't forced into an inferior array model by the C/Java zealots).  It makes the meaning of the upper bound explicit. (Insert rant about broken VB arrays in .NET here...)